# How do I insert a video in CQ5.3?

Tags: video, components, aem

Just started on CQ5. I know there is a video component only on cq5.4 onwards.

So how do I insert a video in CQ5.3?

Comment: Are you hosting the videos inside CQ5, on a third-party service like YouTube or Vimeo, or in a CDN?

Answer (score 3):

You may like to create a component and inside your JSP include the object code with params depending upon which type of video you want to support. Example code-

```
<object width="200px" height="200px" id="your_video_id" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/32545640" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="launch=<%=msnbc.getMSNBCVideoID()%>&amp;width=<%=msnbc.getWidth()%>&amp;height=<%=msnbc.getHeight()%>" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed name="msnbc61868e" src="http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/32545640" width="<%=msnbc.getWidth()%>" height="<%=msnbc.getHeight()%>" FlashVars="launch=<%=msnbc.getMSNBCVideoID()%>&amp;width=<%=msnbc.getWidth()%>&amp;height=<%=msnbc.getHeight()%>" allowscriptaccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</embed>
</object>
```